# C# Deedle.Rplugin R Dataframe to Deedle.Frame

Tags: c#, r, deedle, r.net

I am trying to read a dataframe from the `Rdotnet` environment in C# into `Deedle.Frame` without having to be specific about Types `TRowKey` and `TColumnKey`, since dynamically I may not know the types.

I tried

```
var temp  = RInterop.defaultFromR(engine.GetSymbol(Rvarname).AsDataFrame()); 
//Rvarname is a dataframe in R environment
```

In order to convert this to Frame, I tried -

```
Type ftype = temp.GetType();
Frame< ftype.GetGenericArguments()[0], ftype.GetGenericArguments()[1] > dframe = new Frame<....>()
```

But this does not work since the `GenericArguments()` is not accessible. 
Could you please suggest a way to achieve this without having to sort to using specific Deedle.Rplugin classes like `DataFrameStringStringFromR`, `DataFrameIntStringFromR` etc... ?

Eventually I would like to show the R dataframe in a datagridview, without using loops.

Thank you.